# Recall Commands In Windows With Command Prompt History

Tags: windows, command-line

is there any chance of getting history from previous sessions of Command Line in Windows OS? I have tried Google, however I wasn't in able to find anything relevant.

Comment: No. Sessions in the command window of Windows are not stored. Also, this question is off-topic here, as it's not programming related. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for info on what questions are (and are not) appropriate to ask here. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks CharlesB, so again I would have to deal with core in order to make it happen. @KenWhite Of course, it's programming related. Can't you see the connection between my issue and the programming influence on it?

Comment: No, I can't. If I could, I wouldn't have pointed out it was off-topic. :) Apparently, neither can the two others (so far) that have voted to close it as off-topic.

Comment: They are just following the leader, you. :) I think it is somehow relevant to this site, especially because this is named stackoverflow, not programming stackoverflow, although majority of the topics were directed to be of programming matter in the past ( even though this could be classified as such ).